# Why the typeof the variable is coming undefined in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am declaring the data type of variable in typescript then I am checking the type  of variable , it is giving undefined.

```
var a:number;
console.log(a);
```

But, if I am initializing the variable with some data, then type is shown as `number`. Why so?

Comment: Typescript types are only compile time information. They don't actually change the emitted Javascript, and Javascript has no typed variables, only typed data.

Comment: typeof doesn't tell what the type of a variable is. It tells what the type of the value of the variable is. Your variable has never been initialized, so it has no value, so undefined is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript and Javascript Something hasn't been initialized : undefined